# How to delete rows based on value of first column in matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 3D matrix `xyposframe` and I would like to delete all rows in that matrix where the first column has a number below `150` or over `326`. I tried the following but this didn't give me the desired result:

```matlab
indexbelow = xyposframe(:, 1) < 150;
indexabove = xyposframe(:, 1) > 326;
xyposframe(indexbelow, :) = [];
xyposframe(indexabove, :) = [];
```

How can I delete those rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that both `indexbelow` and `indexabove` are of size n *-by-* 1, i.e. column vectors with as much elements as there are rows in `xyposframe`. With `xyposframe(indexbelow, :) = [];` you remove a number of rows, thus making `xyposframe` have *less* than `n` rows, resulting in an error when you try to call `xyposframe(indexabove, :) = [];`, since you're attempting to index less than `n` elements with a total of `n` indices.

Possible solutions are to split the operation into two parts, or combine them in a single logical statement:

```matlab
% First one, then the other
indexbelow = xyposframe(:, 1) < 150;
xyposframe(indexbelow, :) = [];
indexabove = xyposframe(:, 1) > 326;
xyposframe(indexabove, :) = [];

% Combine using logical AND
indexbelow = xyposframe(:, 1) < 150;
indexabove = xyposframe(:, 1) > 326;
xyposframe(indexbelow & indexabove, :) = [];

% Or put everything in a single indexing line using logical OR
xyposframe(xyposframe(:,1)<150 | xyposframe(:,1) > 326) = [];
```